# pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode - problems with package transparent

Tags: pdftex, texpad, transparent

I am using to compile my MWE

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{transparent}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\texttransparent{0.5}{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

But it won't compile because of the error message `Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode.`.

Whole log:

```
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 623 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  29 JUL 2021 11:44
**
(Ohne Titel.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (transparent.sty
Package: transparent 2016/05/16 v1.1 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)
(ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)

Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode.

) (babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/01/04 3.16 The Babel package
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
) (ngerman.ldf
Language: ngerman 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
(ngermanb.ldf
Language: ngermanb 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
(babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel common definitions
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
)
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
(txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count88
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 125.
))) (Ohne Titel.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \texttransparent
                     {0.5}{Hello World}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

] (Ohne Titel.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
transparent.sty    2016/05/16 v1.1 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
   babel.sty    2018/01/04 3.16 The Babel package
 ngerman.ldf    2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
 ***********

 )
```

Unfortunately I am not able to fix this issue. :/

I am using Texpad on MacOS.

Am I right, that the problem is that pdfTeX is running in DVI mode (which compiles the tex first to a dvi and then to a pdf file) and the transparent package cannot be used in this mode? So I have to switch directly to pdf mode?

I cannot find any settings in Texpad to do so.. :/

Can you help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think on the iPad Texpad only uses it's own TeX engine, which is DVI-based

Comment: if you want only some words transparent you probably can do it with tikz.

Comment: I have the same problem and I read on the Internet that it is due to the use of XeLaTex rather than PDFLaTeX, so that it cannot be avoided (or I did not find how to do).